# Wait for parent resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

According to :

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#what-do-child-states-inherit-from-parent-states

i've pasted the code.

Im trying to make the children wait for parent resolve.
Everything works properl but the problem is the child controller is not being instantiated.
How come ?

edit:

```
$stateProvider.state('parent', {
url: 'parent',
  resolve:{
     resA:  function(){
        return {'value': 'A'};
     }
  },
  controller: function($scope, resA){
      $scope.resA = resA.value;
  }
})
.state('parent.child', {
url: '/child',
  resolve:{
     resB: function(resA){
         console.log('resolve invoked'); // it fires
        return {'value': resA.value + 'B'};
     }
  },
  controller: function($scope, resA, resB){
console.log('done'); //never fired
      $scope.resA2 = resA.value;
      $scope.resB = resB.value;
  }
```

I dont think templates are needed here.

Comment: please, show your exact code. For example, the url and template declarations are missing from the sample code in the documentation.